# listView cannot update dynamically

Tags: java, android, database, listview, sqliteopenhelper

I am using sqlite for database. When i add data in ListView. Data added correctly. But when i close app then updated list lost data which i added before. With code Statically added data shows but using app when create reminder then data added successfully in ListView. But when i restart app **new data lost after restart app**  I mean creating reminder delete automatically after restart app.
Even I delete reminders which added by code after restart app all deleted reminders showing  in ListView again. But Dynamically added data not show.
Please help me to solve this problem.
Here is my Activity code

> RemindersActivity.java

```
package com.example.remindersapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class RemindersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView mlistView;
    private RemindersDbAdapter remindersDbAdapter;
    private ReminderSimpleCursorAdapter reminderSimpleCursorAdapter;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_reminder);
        mlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.reminder_listView);
        //  mlistView.setDivider(null);
        remindersDbAdapter = new RemindersDbAdapter(this);
        remindersDbAdapter.open();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            //clear all data
            remindersDbAdapter.deleteAllReminders();
            //add some data
            insertSomeReminders();

        }

        Cursor cursor = remindersDbAdapter.fetchAllReminders();
        //from columns defined in the db
        String[] from = new String[]{remindersDbAdapter.COL_CONTENT};

        //to the ids of views in the layout
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.row_text};
        reminderSimpleCursorAdapter = new ReminderSimpleCursorAdapter(
                RemindersActivity.this,
                //the layout of the row
                R.layout.reminders_row,
                cursor,
                //from columns defined in the db
                from,
                //to the ids of views in the layout
                to,
                //flag - not used
                0);

//        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
//                this,
//                R.layout.reminders_row,
//                R.id.row_text,
//                new String[]{"fisrt record", "second record", "third record"
//                        , "fourth record", "fifth record"});
        mlistView.setAdapter(reminderSimpleCursorAdapter);
        

        //Adapter is a
        //special Java class defined as part of the Android SDK that functions as the Controller in
        //the Model-View-Controller relationship

        //when we click an individual item in the listview
        mlistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int masterposition, long id) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RemindersActivity.this);
                ListView modeListView = new ListView(RemindersActivity.this);
                String[] modes = new String[]{"Edit Reminder", "Delete Reminder", "Scheduled Reminder"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(RemindersActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, modes);
                modeListView.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
                builder.setView(modeListView);
                final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();

                modeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        //edit reminder
//                        if (position == 0) {
//                            Toast.makeText(RemindersActivity.this, "edit" + masterposition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        } else {
//                            Toast.makeText(RemindersActivity.this, "delete" + masterposition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        }
//                        dialog.dismiss();
                        int nId = getIdFromPosition(masterposition);
                        final Reminder reminder = remindersDbAdapter.fetchReminderById(nId);
                        if (position == 0) {

                            fireCustomDialog(reminder);
                            //delete reminder

                        } else if (position == 1) {
                            remindersDbAdapter.deleteReminderById(getIdFromPosition(masterposition));
                            reminderSimpleCursorAdapter.changeCursor(remindersDbAdapter.fetchAllReminders());

                        }

                        else {
//                            final Date today = new Date();
//                            new TimePickerDialog(RemindersActivity.this,null,today.getHours(),today.getMinutes(),
//                                    false).show();
                            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
//                                    Date alarm = new Date(today.getYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), hourOfDay, minute);
//                                    scheduleReminder(alarm.getTime(), reminder.getmContent());
                                    //This creates a listener for the time picker dialog box. Inside this listener, you use today’s
                                    //date as the base time for your alarm. You then include the hour and minute chosen from
                                    //the dialog box to create the alarm date variable for your reminder. You use both the alarm
                                    //time and the reminder’s content in a new scheduleReminder() method

                                    //Fix the deprecation warnings
                                    final Calendar alarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    alarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay);
                                    alarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                                    scheduleReminder(alarmTime.getTimeInMillis(), reminder.getmContent());

                                }
                            };
                            final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
//                            new TimePickerDialog(RemindersActivity.this, null,
//                                    today.get(Calendar.HOUR), today.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();
                            //the following change to connect the
                            //listener that invokes the BroadcastReceiver to the TimePickerDialog
                            new TimePickerDialog(RemindersActivity.this, listener,
                                    today.get(Calendar.HOUR), today.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();
                        }

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

            }
        });
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            mlistView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            mlistView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

                //The preceding logic defines a MultiChoiceModeListener and attaches it to the ListView.
                //Whenever you long-press an item in the ListView, the runtime invokes the onCreateActionMode()
                //method on the MultiChoiceModeListener. If the method returns with the boolean true value,
                //multichoice action mode is entered.
                @Override
                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.cam_menu, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu_item_delete_reminder:
                            for (int nC = reminderSimpleCursorAdapter.getCount() - 1; nC >= 0; nC--) {
                                if (mlistView.isItemChecked(nC)) {
                                    remindersDbAdapter.deleteReminderById(getIdFromPosition(nC));
                                }
                            }
                            mode.finish();
                            reminderSimpleCursorAdapter.changeCursor(remindersDbAdapter.fetchAllReminders());
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void scheduleReminder(long time, String getmContent) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent.putExtra(ReminderAlarmReceiver.REMINDER_TEXT, getmContent);
        PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, broadcast);
    }

    private int getIdFromPosition(int nC) {
        return (int) reminderSimpleCursorAdapter.getItemId(nC);

    }


    private void insertSomeReminders() {
        remindersDbAdapter.createReminder("Learn android Development", true);
        remindersDbAdapter.createReminder("data Mining Assignment", false);
        remindersDbAdapter.createReminder("Networking Assignment", false);
        remindersDbAdapter.createReminder("English Assignment", true);
        //  //There are several calls to the createReminder() method, each taking a String value
        //with the reminder text and a boolean value flagging the reminder as important. We set
        //a few values to true to provide a good visual effect.
    }

    private void fireCustomDialog(final Reminder reminder) {
        // custom dialog
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom);

        TextView titleView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_title);
        final EditText editCustom = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_reminder);
        Button commitButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_button_commit);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_check_box);
       // checkBox.setChecked(true);
        LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_root_layout);
        final boolean isEditOperation = (reminder != null);


        //this is for an edit
        if (isEditOperation) {
            titleView.setText("Edit Reminder");
            checkBox.setChecked(reminder.getImportant() == 1);
            editCustom.setText(reminder.getmContent());
            rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.check_box));
        }
        commitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String reminderText = editCustom.getText().toString();
                if (isEditOperation) {
                    Reminder reminderEdit = new Reminder(reminder.getmId(),
                            reminderText, checkBox.isChecked() ? 1 : 0);
                    remindersDbAdapter.updateReminder(reminderEdit);
                } else {
                    remindersDbAdapter.createReminder(reminderText, checkBox.isChecked());
                }
                reminderSimpleCursorAdapter.changeCursor(remindersDbAdapter.fetchAllReminders());
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        Button buttonCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_button_cancel);
        buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reminder_menu, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_new:
                //create new reminder
                Log.d(getLocalClassName(), "create new reminder");
                fireCustomDialog(null);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_exit:
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_about:
                fireAboutDialog();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }

    }

    private void fireAboutDialog() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_about);
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

> RemindersDbAdapter.java

```
package com.example.remindersapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class RemindersDbAdapter {

    //these are the column names
    public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_CONTENT =  "content" ;
    public static final String COL_IMPORTANT = "important";

    //these are the corresponding indices

    private static final int INDEX_ID = 0;
    private static final int INDEX_CONTENT = INDEX_ID + 1;
    private static final int INDEX_IMPORTANT = INDEX_ID + 2;

    //used for logging
    private static final String TAG = "RemindersDbAdapter";

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dba_reminder";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_reminder";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private final Context mCtx;

    ////SQL statement used to create the database
    private static final String DATABSE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, " +
            COL_CONTENT + " TEXT, " +
            COL_IMPORTANT + " INTEGER );";

    public RemindersDbAdapter(Context Ctx) {
        //The constructor saves an instance of Context, which is passed to DatabaseHelper
        this.mCtx = Ctx;
    }

//The open()
//method initializes the helper and uses it to get an instance of the database,

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    //the close()
    //method uses the helper to close the database.
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }
    //CREATE
//note that the id will be created for you automatically

    public void createReminder(String name, boolean important) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_CONTENT, name);
        values.put(COL_IMPORTANT, important ? 1 : 0);
        mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);


    }
    ////overloaded to take a reminder

    public long createReminder(Reminder reminder) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_CONTENT, reminder.getmContent()); //Contact name
        values.put(COL_IMPORTANT, reminder.getImportant()); //Contact phone number

        //// Inserting Row
        return mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
    //READ

    public Reminder fetchReminderById(int id) {
        Cursor cursor = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{COL_ID, COL_CONTENT, COL_IMPORTANT},
                COL_ID + " =? ",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        return new Reminder(
                cursor.getInt(INDEX_ID),
                cursor.getString(INDEX_CONTENT),
                cursor.getInt(INDEX_IMPORTANT));


    }

    public Cursor fetchAllReminders() {

        Cursor mcursor = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COL_ID, COL_CONTENT, COL_IMPORTANT},
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mcursor != null) {
            mcursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mcursor;
    }

    //UPDATE
    public void updateReminder(Reminder reminder) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_CONTENT, reminder.getmContent());
        values.put(COL_IMPORTANT, reminder.getImportant());
        mDb.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COL_ID + " =? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(reminder.getmId())});
    }
    //DELETE
    public void deleteReminderById(int id){
        mDb.delete(TABLE_NAME,COL_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }
    public void deleteAllReminders(){
        mDb.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null);
    }

//sqlite open helper

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.w(TAG, DATABSE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABSE_CREATE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + "to " + newVersion + ",which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);


        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

}
```

> ReminderSimpleCursorAdapter.java

```
package com.example.remindersapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class ReminderSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public ReminderSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int i) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to,i);
    }
    ////to use a viewholder, you must override the following two methods and define a ViewHolder class




    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        return super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        if (holder == null){
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.colImp=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.COL_IMPORTANT);
            holder.listTab=view.findViewById(R.id.row_tab);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        if (cursor.getInt(holder.colImp) > 0){
            holder.listTab.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.false_result));

        }else {
            holder.listTab.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.txt_color));
        }
    }
    //Here you see an example of the ViewHolder pattern. This is a well-known Android pattern
    //in which a small ViewHolder object is attached as a tag on each view. This object adds
    //decoration for View objects in the list by using values from the data source, which in this
    //example is the Cursor. The ViewHolder is defined as a static inner class with two instance
    //variables, one for the index of the Important table column and one for the row_tab view you
    //defined in the layout.
    static class ViewHolder{
        //store the column index
        int colImp;
        //store the view
        View listTab;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need this line on your `onOpen()` method: `onCreate(db)`; It will drop your table every time you open your database

Comment: @avdromero Thanks for reply , I remove this line but result is same. EveryTime deleted data show after restart app

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: Wait a minute, you have this remindersDbAdapter.deleteAllReminders(); that deletes all the records, and this method is fired onCreate, where savedInstanceState is always nulll the first time if this activity is the launcher

Comment: @javdromero If i remove this line then after restart app data will be duplicate on screen

Comment: @javdromero thanks for help. I solve this issue to remove the if condition